# Turn different sets with different datatypes into a string separated by a specified delimiter in one function

Tags: java, algorithm, generics

For Example 
a set{1,2,3,4,5} with a delimiter @
I want to have a return string of 1@2@3@4@5

The tricky part is, I have many different sets,

```
Set<Integer>, Set<String>, Set<Long> and so on.
```

And I know I can do it in separate functions using a loop. But I just don't want to be tedious and want to do it in one function using Java Generics or whatever that can help. I have done some brain storm but in vain. :(

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [join](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String)) method of [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/) class of the [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library

Example:

```
Set<Integer> theSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
theSet.add(1);
theSet.add(2);
theSet.add(3);
theSet.add(4);
theSet.add(5);
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(theSet,'@'));
```

***Output***: 1@2@3@4@5

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you are missing the add method call on theSet

Answer (score 0):

Edit: [the answer from mabbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594585/658663) is a better idea than this.

It's not particularly great, but will work assuming that your Set contains objects whose toString representations you want to concatenate

```
public String concatenateSet(Set<?> set) {
    return set.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .reduce((previous, current) -> previous + "@" + current)
            .orElse("");
}
```

Step by step:

Calling stream() gets you a stream of items in the set

Calling map(Object::toString) calls toString on each item of the set

Calling reduce((previous, current) -> previous + "@" + current) concatenates the toString representations of each object with @ as a delimiter between each item

Calling orElse("") will ensure that an empty sting is returned if, for example, the set is empty

Answer (score 0):

You're over thinking it.  You can just take a Set as a parameter and it will cover every type of set.  Just make sure your objects implement toString().

```
public static String setToString(Set set)
{
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(it.next().toString());
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        out.append("@" + it.next());
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think op is looking for a String to be returned by the function, rather than sysout of the concatenated Set

Comment: It's the same idea either way.  They just need one function that will handle sets of any type of object.  Technically you are correct though...  Fixed it.